# Can I migrate purchase between applications in macOS App Store?

Tags: nsbundle, mac-app-store, receipt-validation

I have several similar applications (A1-A3) with hugely the same codebase. They all do similar things (diagrams), each with a specialisation for a specific use case. I am now considering to create one app (B) that sells the specialisations as an Mac App Store In App Purchase. So basically, I reduce number of applications, but will provide same diagrams, just change how to sell them from dedicated app to in-app.

How can I best ensure that buyers of the "old" applications A1-A3 can use the specialisations they bought in the new software B? I don’t want to charge them twice. So, they should be able to “restore” the specialisation that they bought as a A2 in B. Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Within app B do following steps in the background or on click of the restore IAP-button:

- Look for the "old" app A1-A3 using `NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier`
- get the receipt of this bundle using `appStoreReceiptURL`
- validate the receipt
- unlock functionality

Bare in mind that the terms and conditions of Apple say something along the line of "only appstore IAP should be used to unlock features; don't roll your own license mechanism"

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this. It looks simple enough, so I am on the right track. Thank you. Will accept answer once I have implemented it.

Comment: i had it up and running; for most users it works.  sandboxing and several instances of the bundle on the developer machine (inside xcode archives) made it a pain to test. strongly advise using guest account and/or another cleanly installed mac.

Comment: I just reread. Update old software? I assume update to new software application?

Comment: Done, I hope it makes more sense now.