# How do I tell if an app was already purchased (licensed) by purchasing an older version on the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I've experienced a few apps that have had some time on the Mac App Store, but were later removed either by Apple or the developer for whatever reason. The developer then followed up with an offer where you could register the app by downloading one from their site onto your system with the App Store version already installed, which would unlock the full features of the new download.

How does one go about verifying an authentic purchase like that? Ideally I'd prefer examples in Swift if you would be so kind, but ObjC is manageable as well.

Comment: Normally this can be done by verifying the receipt inside the .app...

Comment: This has never really made much sense to me. If you can post some simple sample code, I'd be happy to mark that as the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458289/verifying-the-purchase-receipt-of-another-application-mac-app-store/51765513#51765513

Comment: and duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480313/can-i-migrate-purchase-between-applications-in-macos-app-store/50488040#50488040

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verifying the purchase (receipt) of another application (Mac App Store)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458289/verifying-the-purchase-receipt-of-another-application-mac-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

Here are official docs about receipt validation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html

There’s also WWDC 2013 video 308 called “Using Receipts to Protect Your Digital Sales”.

It’s recommended to implement your own validation code, but it’s overwhelming and error prone if you’re new to this. There are projects on GitHub that can get you started.